# Logical Error in given program cannot find it

Tags: c++, math, runtime-error, c++14

**In this problem we are given two arrays attackArray and defArray both of size N.**

Now we think each array element to be a say, solider.
We need to output the particular element which is greater than its neighbours & greater than their sum. If multiple elements can the output then output the largest one.

**-1 If no such element is found.**

**Custom input I tried to run it with**

**Input**

```
4
4
1 1 4 1
3 4 2 1
7
5 4 5 4 5 4 5
3 2 4 7 2 5 9
3
5 8 1
5 6 20
20
46 35 17 37 39 48 10 49 44 11 36 4 2 22 16 41 26 8 15 40
4 41 6 35 49 50 28 46 22 17 13 36 31 2 33 14 150 47 29 39
```

**Output**

```
3
-1
20
-1
```

**.Last output should've been 150.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    if (T > 100 || T < 1)
        return 0;

    do {
        vector<int> ans;
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        if (N > 100 || N < 3)
            return 0;
        vector<long long int> attackArray(N), defArray(N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            cin >> attackArray.at(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            cin >> defArray.at(i);
        }
        if (defArray.at(0) > attackArray.at(1) && defArray.at(0) > attackArray.at(N - 1) && defArray.at(0) > attackArray.at(1) + attackArray.at(N - 1)) {

            ans.push_back(defArray.at(0));
        }
        if (defArray.at(N - 1) > attackArray.at(0) && defArray.at(N - 1) > attackArray.at(N - 2) && defArray.at(N - 1) > attackArray.at(0) + attackArray.at(N - 2)) {

            ans.push_back(defArray.at(N - 1));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
            int nexti, previ;

            nexti = i + 1;
            previ = i - 1;

            if (defArray.at(i) > attackArray.at(nexti) && defArray.at(i) > attackArray.at(previ) && defArray.at(i) > attackArray.at(nexti) + attackArray.at(previ)) {

                ans.push_back(defArray.at(i));
            }
            else {
                ans.push_back(-1);
                break;
            }
        }

        sort(ans.begin(), ans.end(), greater<int>());
        cout << ans[0] << endl;

        T--;
    } while (T != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How "neighbors" are defined? Is `defArray.at(0)` neighbor for `attackArray.at(0)`?

Comment: For defArray.at(i) neighbours are one to its left and other to its right IN attackArray. Elements are in circular pattern so defArray.at(0) right is attackArray.at(1) and left would warp around the array to be the last element of attackArray ie, N-1

Comment: Yes, it is assumed in your code. But does problem statement declare this explicitly?

Comment: Yes. https://www.codechef.com/FEB19B/problems/DEPCHEF

Comment: What `ans` contains after item 150 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for the first line because the first element in defArray is larger than the attack of the neighbours so it doesn't need to enter the loop (you check specially for the first element).

It works for the third line because the last element in defArray is larger than the attack of the neighbours so it doesn't need to enter the loop (you check specially for the last element).

It doesn't work for any item in the loop after the first one because as soon as something in defArray is not larger than the attack of the neighbours you call `break;` and exit the loop.  You need to check every element in defArray but the loop stops as soon as any element fails.   Why are you calling `break;` anyway?

I haven't tested all the boundary conditions but removing the `break;` does seem to fix it...

Comment: Okay I will try that